# Riemann integrability and lower and upper sums

Tags: analysis

Let's say a function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and Riemann integrable, then would there always exist a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that the lower sum of  $P$ equals the upper sum of $P$?

My guess is "No" because the Riemann integrability implies that the infimum of upper sums equals the supremum of lower sums, but I am struggling to come up with a proof or counter-example.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower and upper sums are sums of areas of rectangles.  It should be clear from a diagram that unless $f$ is constant (or at any rate piecewise constant) we will always have
$$\{\hbox{lower sum}\}<\{\hbox{exact area}\}<\{\hbox{upper sum}\}\ .$$
For a specific example simply take $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$.  You should not find it hard to show that for any partition $P$,
$$\{\hbox{lower sum}\}<\frac12<\{\hbox{upper sum}\}\ .$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice and concise explanation and example.